# I want to know how to get "Gnome" Started

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 32 bit and want to know how to get the gnome gui up and running. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start Unity. Issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

then reboot. If you really need Gnome:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: There is no need to add a third party repository to install gnome-shell.